# Problem with Ubuntu first run

Tags: installation, boot, uninstall

Today i installed the ubuntu system and everything went well.

When the computer restarted and I chose linux, it showed me just a purple screen and nothing else; just a blank purple screen.

Now, I don't know what to do with it, how to un-install it or how to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please define your question. For more details on best practices consider reading the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) on asking questions.Regards

Comment: While booting press F1 and paste the last lines of the output here which will help us in figuring out your issue

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually to uninstall it, you simply override Ubuntu, such as reinstalling Ubuntu on that partition, installing another OS, delete the partition, or reformat the partition. Frequently reinstalling Ubuntu solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

boot with a live cd, run gparted and delete/format partition

Comment: and how i do it ? i cant do anything with a cd i have to today it with a flash drive

Comment: here you have all you need to create a bootable flash pen http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download, just go to step 2, select USB stick and your host OS (ubuntu or windows)